# How to know google maps is installed in iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I am developing an application in which i need to know which are already installed in iPhone  device such as google maps. I need to check it. cause I know some country can't support google maps. In this case, what can I do that?

Comment: Why Google Maps and not the default map application ?

Comment: Are you talking about Google Maps shortcut to the web?

Comment: In china, can't support google maps. so I have no choice.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can't unless you find an API. And even if you find it, there are chances you get rejected from the AppStore.

However, you can try with the [URL schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes). For Google Maps, it will invoke the application of it finds an URL starting with `http://maps.google.com/`.

So, add this function to your code :

```
- (BOOL)isGoogleMapsInstalled { 
     return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
          canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Paris"]]; 
}
```

It's not very "clean" but should works.